# Different download url for same url

Tags: firefox, https, firefox-addon, download, wget

In firefox browser when we download file from google-drive, using the default downloader of Firefox the download url is

URL 1:

```
https://doc-04-8k-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/dc96gf00f84kd0c127s2cise8ks8n5ld/7afccipdbmdoi126997bca4fr99lnqqd/1421582400000/02072504278905675512/02072504278905675512/0B1LDhFl3Mq71UWpIYk9RWUVPbXQ2WkdpUnRFaUd3dnRDeTlV?e=download
```

But when downloading the same file with downthemall addon the url is changed to
URL 2:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B1LDhFl3Mq71UWpIYk9RWUVPbXQ2WkdpUnRFaUd3dnRDeTlV&export=download
```

Same happens for gmail also
URL 3:

```
https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/u/0/?ui=2&ik=428d6bbfb6&view=att&th=1495bdf259eb986f&attid=0.1&disp=safe&zw&saduie=AG9B_P_mly2BAAjLWP5erVUkKOc2&sadet=1421583992369&sads=-KDNovGBxNBq4x0curLcaiuA8Uk
```

URL 4:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=428d6bbfb6&view=att&th=1495bdf259eb986f&attid=0.1&disp=safe&zw
```

When I am trying to use URL 1 or URL3 with wget, then in that case html file is downloaded which is basically google login page.

I will appreciate if anyone explain from what downnloadthem all is doing behind the scene?

Comment: There is a guy that can explain it, he's busy lately but he's the author of the addon. Just be patient and he'll definitely answer you :)

Comment: @Noitidart No Problem, I can wait seriously. I am very new to this and I am interpreted in understanding all these